# flutter inverted border radius

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

How do I apply a border radius similar to the one shown in the image below? like home icon

I looked on Google, but some of the solutions were confusing. I couldn't figure out how to do the inverted rounded corners thing.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To get the curved corners on this outer container, you just need to apply a border radius to the top-left and bottom-right corners. Here is a sample code

specify the desired height, width, and radius for rounding the corners

```
Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
          ),
          child: Icon(Icons.home)),
```

If you want to curve all the corners, use `BorderRadius.circular()`.Like below

```
Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: Icon(Icons.home)),
```

Comment: I am referring to the home item, which has a black background and a inverted border.

Comment: @RuhulAmin One approach to get the black space appearance is as follows: first, create the topmost white container with top-left border radius and bottom-right border radius. Then, leave some space and proceed to create the home container. keep the same space as previously specified after the home container as well. Finally, create the bottom white container with top-right border radius. These three containers should be nested within a parent container, whose background color is set to black. This will automatically result in the desired black curve appearance. Ask for any clarifications.